# Want to ask a question about Creationism and Evolution

Tags: discussion

What are the rational objections raised against Creationism?

Creationism is the belief that the universe was created in six days as some interpret is stated in the Bible.

I have been following the Creationist/Evolutionist argument for some time, and it appears that the Creationist point of view draws its arguments from the Biblical text and an interpretation of it.

While this may be sufficient to dismiss Creationism as a sicentific theory, I am not sure if the concept of creationism is really irrational or self-contradictory.

What  philosophical objections based on irrationality have been put forward against the Creationist belief?

Comment: What is your question? Philosophy Meta is a place to ask questions about the main site.

Comment: I want to ask the question "What are the rational objections raised against Creationism?"

Comment: What is the question for Philosophy Meta?

Comment: The question is : is this question OK?                                                    Q: What are the rational objections raised against Creationism?

Creationism is the belief that the universe was created in six days as some interpret is stated in the Bible.

I have been following the Creationist/Evolutionist argument for some time, and it appears that the Creationist point of view draws its arguments from the Biblical text and an interpretation of it.

While this may be sufficient to dismiss Creationism as a sicentific theory, I am not sure if t........

Comment: I don't see why not. Do you have a specific reason why you would think it is not okay? Otherwise, I would just ask it on the main site and see how it is received.

Comment: Thanks, will go ahead with question. Actually starting off I had a few bad experiences and downvotes so I needed to learn to ask a specific question with a possible specific answer. This is not a forum.